# Mac Terminal theme - text-colors not working

Tags: macos, terminal, colors, themes

I'm using the Mac Terminal more frequently and was using the Homebrew theme (green text, black background). Now I wanted to set a new theme which had different text colors. The one I tried using was this one: https://github.com/hukl/Smyck-Color-Scheme (and also another one).

The problem with this is that the text-colors just don't work. 
If you look at the screenshots at that url, you see that in `vim` the text has different colors. Same for `git-diff` and `ls`, `ls -g` or `ls -a`.

For me all text is the white this theme uses.

At the advanced-tab `Declare Terminal as` is set to `xterm-256color`. Also `Display ANSI colors` is enabled.

I don't want to use another terminal, like iTerm or something.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

In your home directory try editing your `.bash_profile` (since Mac OS X 10.8) — or for 10.7 and earlier, either `.profile,` `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` (depending on availability,) and add following code:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```